# Mejor opción: Windows Docker vs Compilar en Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, docker

Os quería realizar la siguiente consulta.
Tengo una aplicación Asp.net Core 2.0 desarrollada en Visual Studio 15.4.3.

Todo perfecto, la publico en IIS y funciona.
Ahora quería dar un paso mas y poder publicarla en un servidor Linux.

La primera opción que veo que se comenta por ahí es utilizar Docker, lo he visto por encima, hasta instalado en Windows y trasteado un poco, aunque no he creado el contenedor todavía.

Pero de mientras se me ha ocurrido (que igual es una tontería) sino seria mas sencillo copiar el proyecto al servidor Linux y ahí compilar-publicar la aplicación.

O la solución de visual de desarrollo y sus configuraciones cambia de un entorno a otro?

Seria mas correcto meterse a fondo con el Docker?

Bueno en conclusión, que experiencias tenéis vosotros, ventajas y desventajas si realmente la segunda opción que comento es posible.

Answer (score 0):

Mi recomendación es que arranques un docker linux que monte un volumen (bind) compartido en el que tengas tu código fuente. De ese modo no tendrás que copiarlo. 
Tras compilarlo en linux te debería funcionar.

Esto funciona en linux a la perfección, entre distintos tipos de distribuciones. Por ejemplo, mi host tiene un directorio con el código fuente clonado de github (también podrías usar svn), y luego lanza distintos dockers (uno con Linux RedHat, otro con Ubuntu), cada uno con sus librerías, y compila el código con la versión gcc que requiera, librerías propias de la distribución, etc.
Entiendo que para Windows debería ser similar aunque no lo he probado.